# How to WRITE to ext4 partitions on windows?

Tags: drivers, partitioning, windows, ext4

I've tried many of the answers found here. Even the ones that supposedly could write to the SD card, won't work. When I eject the card and put it again the file is like it was before the write.

So how to **write** to SD cards in windows? I just need to edit a text file with notepad++.

Comment: You will need the aid of a 3rd party program to read / write to an ext4 formatted disk in Windows.  They do exist out there but they may not be reliable.  There is no program in Ubuntu that would allow Windows to see that drive.  The only other thing you could try is backup the drive to something else, then format it as FAT32 so that the drive can be read natively from both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed some program which acted like a drive. The SD card simply appeared on the windows explorer as a regular card. I clicked edit with notepadd++ and did control S to save. This way won't work. If I save the file to the desktop and then place it on the SD card the windows asks me to replace the file. This way it will work. Would be nice to have a way to explicitly edit files rapidly on windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ext2fsd. It is kind of driver that you install in Windows:

https://sourceforge.net/p/ext2fsd/code/ci/master/tree/